# gmaps4rails gem, always use cluster icon instead of marker icon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, gmaps4rails

Working with Google-Maps-for-Rails gem. Useful gem!

For privacy reasons, we're clustering markers. When there is only one marker however, the marker icon appears instead of the cluster icon.

When there is only one marker, instead of the individual marker icon, we would like the cluster icon to appear with a "1" on it. Is this possible? If so how?

Currently, clustering is on.

```
<%= gmaps("markers" =>
             {
               "data" => @fundings_for_map,
               "options" => {"clusterer_gridSize" => 50,
                             "do_clustering" => true,
                             "clusterer_maxZoom" => 100}
             }, etc...
```

Tried messing with maxZoom, but individual markers still appear as markers instead of clusters.

Anyone have any ideas if it's possible to display only cluster icons and if so how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you should restrict the zoom level for the map and the clusterer

Comment: @apneadiving, Thanks for the response.

We adjusted the maxZoom on the map to 10, and the clusterer maxZoom to 12. However, the individual markers still appear as individual markers because they were never clustered in the first place.

One solution we came up with was to hide individual markers, but that made the map seem too sparse. 

Our second solution was to replace the default single marker icon, with a cluster style icon with a "1" in it. This "solved" the problem. However, if there is a more elegant solution, we'd love to hear it.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. Please help!